# Tracking changes in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots, qtreewidget

I have an editable `QTreeWidget` and wish to update some internal structures every time the user edits an item. However, there's no signal emitted specifically when some item is changed. There is `itemChanged()`, but it's emitted not only when the item is changed, but when it is *created* as well. So far I can't find an elegant way to distinguish between the two cases.

The only solution I invented was something like this:

```
# slot for itemClicked()
def EditName(self, item, column):
    self.oldname = item.text(0)

# slot for itemChanged()
def RenameFile(self, item, column):
    newname = item.text(0)
    if newname != self.oldname:
        # Do something with newname here
```

However, it's not very convenient because I'll have to set `self.oldname` manually any time I add a new item to the tree, which happens in quite a lot of places in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to track changes would be to create a subclass of `QTreeWidgetItem` and reimplement its [`setData`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setData) function.

The reimplemeted function could then check the [`role`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) argument to see which action to take:

```
class TreeWidgetItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setFlags(self.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)

    def setData(self, column, role, value):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            # do important stuff here...
            print 'before: "%s", after: "%s"' % (
                self.text(column), value.toString())
        QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.setData(self, column, role, value)
```